# Reference request: Riks method (Nonlinear FEM)

Tags: finite-element, nonlinear-equations, reference-request, solid-mechanics

I'm struggling to find a good detailed reference explaining the Arc-length method or, more generally, Riks method and its derivations. I looked for the classical books in nonlinear mechanics (the ones by Crisfield, De Borst, Bathe, etc) but they're confusing for a beginner in nonlinear analysis. Thus, I'd like to request for references regarding the Arc-length method for systems of nonlinear equations. I'm not new to FEM and I'm aware of Newton-Raphson method but the problem I'm dealing with presents a *snap-through* behavior due to softening of the material.

Comment: Have you checked section 6.5.3 of Belytschko, Ted, et al. Nonlinear finite elements for continua and structures. John wiley & sons, 2013.?

Comment: @nicoguaro yes and it still seems a bit tough to me regarding implementation. I was looking for a reference showing how to solve it at least for a single equation, something like a step-by-step procedure.

Comment: Well, I have seen material like that for linear analysis but never for the nonlinear counterpart. But, I hope I'm wrong, and there is something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that Crisfield's book is not a clear place to start for this topic.  Have you read the original paper by Riks, ["An incremental approach to the solution of snapping and buckling problems", IJSS 1979](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020768379900817)?  It is quite clear in my opinion.  If you don't have access, I can send it to you.  I believe the modification by Crisfield is widely used, and his paper ["A fast incremental/iterative solution procedure that handles 'snap-through'", Computers & Structures 1981](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0045794981901085) is also clearly written.  If you have any specific questions about implementation I can try to help.

Comment: OskarM, could you provide a step-by-step procedure? I was trying to solve a single equation as follows: [K(u)].{u} = {F} with the Stiffness Matrix as [K(u)] = u+1; Displacement vector {u} = u and Force vector {F} = 2. I guess by solving this very simple equation then the procedure for a system of nonlinear equations will be straightforward.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your notation.  I don't know what you mean to indicate by the square brackets in [K(u)], nor by the curly braces in {F}.  I also don't know what you mean by [K(u)] = u+1, {u}=u, or {F} = 2.

Can you try to explain a bit more what you mean?  I would be happy to summarize Riks' method, as developed in his original paper, as well as the modification by Crisfield, but it will take more space than one comment.

Comment: [ ] is a matrix and { } a vector. Since this case is a single equation, [K(u)] is a 1x1 matrix; {u} and {F} are 1x1 vectors. K(u) is just to say that the Stiffness Matrix is a function of the unknowns "u", which means this is a nonlinear problem. Thus, I'm trying to solve u²+u = 2.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean - you want to apply Riks' method to a problem with a single degree of freedom for the displacement variable.  You have two variables - the loading, and the scalar displacement.

I'm still not sure about your terminology.  The general problem is usually described as a nonlinear system, $F(u)=0$.  In elasticity, $F$ is a force, which can be decomposed into applied loads and internal stresses.  Then the problem is linearized to get $K(u) du + F(u) = 0$, where $K$ is the stiffness matrix/Jacobian of F, and $du$ is the incremental displacement, which is solved for.

Comment: Anyway, I'm working on an edit to include a step-by-step procedure but I probably won't get to it tonight.  The basic idea of Riks' method is to add a "control" equation to govern the loading parameter.  For spherical arc-length control, you would have the equation $d\lambda^2+|du|^2=R^2$, where $d\lambda$ is the load increment and $R$ is the step size, which is typically tuned to get efficient convergence of Newton's method.  There is no equation that looks like $u^2+u=2$, unless I'm missing something specific to your question.

Comment: K(u) is the Stiffness matrix which is a function of "u" (I adopted it as "u+1"), {u} is the unknown vector and {F} = 2 is the applied external force vector. Thinking about Structural Mechanics, that could be thought as a rod with **u(0) = 0** and with a applied force _F=2_ at **u = L**. If something is missing that's probably because I didn't understood the Riks' method haha.